# Dart: Cannot convert 'List<dynamic>' to 'List<Map<String, Object>>' Error: 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>'

Tags: flutter, dart

I stored a variable with List<Map<String, Object>> type in SharedPreferences after encoding it to JSON. But when I decode it, it comes back as List. I am unable to convert it into List<Map<String, Object>>. When I do, I get the following error:

'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>'

Please Help!

```
List<Map<String, Object>> list = [];
list.add({'time': dateStr, 'name': 'summa', 'points': number.toString()});
String? encodedList = json.encode(list);
await prefs.setString('Values', encodedList);
final String? encodedList2 = prefs.getString('Values');
List<Map<String, Object>> decodedList = json.decode(encodedList2) as List<Map<String, Object>>;
```

Comment: What is `encodedList`? From where it comes from? Can you add how you instantiate/populate it?

Comment: Sorry just corrected it. I encoded time, name and points and stored it in the shared preferences (Values). Then I retrieved it and stored in encodedList2 variable. Then I decoded it and I want the decoded variable to be List<Map<String,Object>>.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to construct the `List<Map<String, Object>>` in multiple steps, like so:

```dart
final listOfDynamics = json.decode(encodedList) as List<dynamic>;
final listOfMaps = listOfDynamics.map((element) => element as Map<String, dynamic>);
final listOfStringObjectMaps = listOfMaps.map((element) => element.map((key, value) => MapEntry(key, value as Object)));
```

Personally I would skip the last step and keep the maps as `Map<String, dynamic>`. They're generally easier to work with when doing JSON related operations.

Comment: The second line can be simplified to: `final listOfMaps = listOfDynamics.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();`

Comment: Stick a `toList()` on wherever you have that iterable.

Comment: @Richard, its getting more complicated. If possible please provide your solution as an answer to my above question. I am stuck with this one :(

Comment: I tried to fix it but I am getting the following error now: 'MappedListIterable<Map<String, dynamic>, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, Object>>'

Comment: You should accept this answer and ask a new one with updated code based on where you have made progress and where you are stuck.

Comment: @ManoHaran Try adding a `toList()` to the end of `listOfStringObjectMaps` (e.g. `final listOfStringObjectMaps = (...).toList()`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `toList<T>(dyanmicData)` global function in the [flutter_helper_utils](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_helper_utils) package:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_helper_utils/flutter_helper_utils.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

 final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

 final dataList = [
    {
      'time': DateTime.now().toString(),
      'name': 'summa',
      'points': '1',
    },
  ];

  String encodedList = json.encode(dataList);
  await prefs.setString('Values', encodedList);

  final String? storedEncodedList = prefs.getString('Values');

  if (storedEncodedList != null) {
    final decodedList =
        toList<Map<String, dynamic>>(json.decode(storedEncodedList));
    print(decodedList);
  }
```

Note: if `toList(dyanmicData)` name conflicts with any of your methods you can call its static one using `ConvertObject.toList<T>(dyanmicData)`.

You can also use the global `makeMapEncodable(map)` on each of your `dataList`, which returns a map with fixes of any unsupported type in your map values and converts it to String so the encode function does not encounter any runtime errors in the feature.